# Function executed three times

Tags: javascript, jquery, iterator

```
$('[name="properties_box"]').change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {

        console.log(properties.length - 1);

        for (var i = 0; i < (properties.length - 1); i++) {

            (function(index) {
                console.log('iterator: ' + index);
                //do ajax here
            })(i);

        }

    }
});
```

It should only log 0-7. But it does it three times like this.

```
7 main.js?ver=20130905:732
iterator: 0 main.js?ver=20130905:737
iterator: 1 main.js?ver=20130905:737
iterator: 2 main.js?ver=20130905:737
iterator: 3 main.js?ver=20130905:737
iterator: 4 main.js?ver=20130905:737
iterator: 5 main.js?ver=20130905:737
iterator: 6 main.js?ver=20130905:737
7 main.js?ver=20130905:732
iterator: 0 main.js?ver=20130905:737
iterator: 1 main.js?ver=20130905:737
iterator: 2 main.js?ver=20130905:737
iterator: 3 main.js?ver=20130905:737
iterator: 4 main.js?ver=20130905:737
iterator: 5 main.js?ver=20130905:737
iterator: 6 main.js?ver=20130905:737
7 main.js?ver=20130905:732
iterator: 0 main.js?ver=20130905:737
iterator: 1 main.js?ver=20130905:737
iterator: 2 main.js?ver=20130905:737
iterator: 3 main.js?ver=20130905:737
iterator: 4 main.js?ver=20130905:737
iterator: 5 main.js?ver=20130905:737
iterator: 6
```

Can someone explain why and how to fix it? I am going to have some AJAX call within, so it's important that it doens't run more than needed.

Comment: It might be binding the .change() more than once on the object.  Before the bind try this to see if that is the problem: `$('[name="properties_box"]').unbind()`

Comment: can you provide a fiddle for it because your code don't seem to be wrong.

Comment: What's `properties`? Show your HTML as well.

Comment: I think $('[name="properties_box"]'). length be 3

Comment: Can you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) version?

Comment: @Sudharsan I suspect the same

Comment: Unbind worked very well, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem with binding the change three times,
Refered to the comments posted i suggest this as answer

```
$('[name="properties_box"]').unbind()
```

Before the bind event called use above code.